# Show the centralisers $C_{S_6}(s)$ and $C_{S_6}(t)$ are isomorphic to $S_{3} \times C_{3}$

Tags: group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

> Let $s=(123)$ and $t=(123)(456)$ be elements of $S_6$. Show the
> centralisers $C_{S_6}(s)$ and $C_{S_6}(t)$ are isomorphic to $S_{3}
>  \times C_{3}$.

**My thoughts:**
Using the definition, $C_{S_6}(s)=\{g \in S_{6} : g^{-1}sg=s\}=\{g \in S_6 : (g(1)  g(2)  g(3))=(123)\}$.
So we need to identify the elements $g \in S_{6}$ which leave $(123)$ intact (but may have any effect on 4,5,6). But I don't see how to identify this with $S_{3} \times C_{3}$.

With $t=(123)(456)$ this is even more confusing to me. How do I show this isomorphism?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You should be able to complete the proof for $s$ - you are nearly there. Roughly speaking, the $C_3$ is generated by $s = (1,2,3)$, and the $S_3$ is just the action on $\{4,5,6\}$. I agree that $C_G(t)$ is a little harder, but you could start by writing down some permutations that centralize it.

Comment: Of course if you happened to know that there is an exceptional outer automorphism of $S_6$ mapping $(1,2,3) \to (1,2,3)(4,5,6)$, then that would make the proof a lot simpler, but I expect that's cheating!

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks for your reply. Okay I see now why the first part is true. but I am still stuck on why $C_{G}(t)$ is true. I just don't get why we pick A and B like in kabenyuk's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints.
Let $A=\langle(123)(456)\rangle$, $B=\langle(14)(25)(35),(123)(465)\rangle$. Then

1. $C(t)=AB$;
2. $A\cong C_3$, $B\cong S_3$;
3. $AB\cong C_3\times S_3$.

Comment: Thanks for your  reply. But why did you choose A and B in this way?  I don't see why $C(t) = AB$. I tried multiplying the generator of A with the generators of B to figure out why but this didn't help me to understand

Comment: It is easy to see that $A,B\subset C(t)$ therefore $AB\leq C(t)$. Then we know that $|t^{S_6}|=40$ and $|S_6:C(t)|=|t^{S_6}|$. Hence, $|C(t)|=18$. Since $|AB|=18$ and $AB\leq C(t)$, it follows that $AB=C(t)$.